# ¿Porque obtengo como resultado NaN?

Tags: javascript

Debo calcular el promedio de todos los números en un array de números (y ponerlo en una función) ej.: `calcularPromedio([10,5,4,2,8])`

Pero obtengo como resultado `NaN`

```
function calcularPromedio(arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];    
    }
    return sum / arr.length;
}

console.log(calcularPromedio([10, 5, 4, 2, 8]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al usar `i <= arr.length;` en el bucle, el array se desborda en la última iteracción, porque los índices de los arrays empiezan por `0` y cuando busca elemento en el índice `5` no lo encuentra, produciendo un `undefined` que provoca que el resultado de la suma **no sea un número** (en Javascript `NaN` significa ***N***ot **a** **N**umber).

Para evitar que la lectura del array se desborde, tienes que poner la condición así:

```
i < arr.length;
```

```js
function calcularPromedio(arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i]; 
    }
    return sum / arr.length;
}

console.log(calcularPromedio([10, 5, 4, 2, 8]));
```

Comment: Son 5 elementos (length del array), pero el indice va de 0 al 4

Comment: Así es @PatrickArguello, auque Juan respondió antes. Yo estaba revisando el snippet. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas recorriendo mas posiciones de las que hay en el array
`arr.length` te trae como resultado 5 y deberias recorrer desde la posicion 0 al 4

```
i <= arr.length
```

debería ser:

```
i < arr.length
```